# Windows 10 technical Preview Key Not Working

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I am trying to install Windows 10 technical preview on VirtualBox and it requires a product key. I used the default key `NKJFK-GPHP7-G8C3J-P6JXR-HQRJR`. It says it could not be verified. Any ideas?

EDIT:
The exact error message is: 'We couldn't verify the product key. Please check your installation media'

Comment: which Build do you try to install? normally you don't need a key. Also make sure you don't try to install the Enterprise version.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I installed the 'Windows10_TechnicalPreview_x64_EN-US_9926'. I do not think that is the enterprise version.

Comment: create an ISO of Build 10049 and try again to install: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_install/instructions-create-a-bootable-iso-file-using-esd/1d64c65c-f619-4193-9bce-d6ed5d3b66da

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are connected to internet and again try using the same key, if it won't work try this key instead it may work PBHCJ-Q2NYD-2PX34-T2TD6-233PK

Comment: I am connected to the internet and tried both keys. Still says cannot be verified.